# Google Chrome extension: background page or event page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Google Chrome extension at the moment and I have a question about when to use an event page.

A quick look at the [Chrome extension docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) shows that Google really want its developers to use event pages, if possible.

My extension currently uses a background page, but I was wondering if I should switch to an event page?

This is what my extension does:

- When matched with a particular website, it injects a script that adds buttons for the user to access extra functionality.
- Most of this extra functionality consists of doing fairly computationally expensive operations on user-entered data - this is all done in the background page (it is all it does).
- When a user wants to run these operations on their data they press a button and this passes a message, from the injected script to the background page, which then passes a message back containing the results of its operations.

Essentially, all the background page is doing is waiting for message passing from an injected script in one particular website and then running some operations. Since it doesn't need to be active all the time, this suggests that I should be using an event page.

**Can anyone confirm if this would be a good idea for me? Or are there reasons why I should stick to a background page?**

Comment: Avoid using persistent background pages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935117/event-pages-and-background-pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing the background page to suspend (chrome.runtime.onSusend) is great, because it will free up system resources. The page will automatically be launched when a matching event happens (chrome.tab.onUpdated etc). I can't think of any compelling reason to use a persistent background page. You can always store any long term state in chrome.storage.local or indexedDb, etc.

Comment: The only reason to use a persistent background page is if you use an API that doesn't work otherwise e.g. chrome.webRequest or chrome.webNavigation, etc.