# The difference between event page and background page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

After I read  the documentation about [Event Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) I didn't got the advantage of using Event Page instead of Background Page .

Suppose I have the follow simple case  -

**manifest.json**

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
}, 
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }
]
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("Hi Background")
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(messageListener);

function messageListener (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert(request);   
}
```

In this case , whether `persistent` is `"persistent": false` or `"persistent": true` the listener in the `background.js` always should be awake in order to get the messages from the `content.js` and therefore the the `background.js` couldn't go to suspend mode .

So what is the benefit of the Event Page (`"persistent": true`) in such cases and in general ? Please provide an example.

Comment: It'll be unloaded after about 5 seconds of inactivity, which is the selling point. A message from content script will load it. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Older question on the same topic with my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935117/event-pages-and-background-pages/23935436

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main advantage of the event pages is to release RAM and CPU resources by unloading background script when it is not used.

> ...background.js couldn't go to suspend mode.

It can. Even if your event page uses message listener it still will be unloaded after some time. Chrome remembers that the page has set the listener, so the browser will awake the page when a message will be sent.

You can try this experiment:

1. add this extension

*manifest.json*

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },      
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

*background.js*

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    sendResponse({
        msg: "it's alive!"
    });
  }
);
```

*popup.html*

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="text"></div>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

*popup.js*

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('hello', 
    function (response) {
        document.getElementById('text').textContent = response.msg;
    }
);
```

2. Open Chrome's Task manager and wait few seconds until Test extension disappears (unloads). If you do not see it (it already unloaded), you can reload extension.
3. Click to the extension's browser action and you will see message inside the window which came from the event page. Also, you can see two processes in the task manager for the Test extension: one is a popup and the second is the event page. 

   After popup will be closed, the event page unloads again in a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks. So as a user of this extension it wouldn't be any felt change on both `"persistent": false` or `"persistent": true` . But as a developer  for which reason could I prefer `"persistent": true` rather than `"persistent": false` ?

Comment: @URL87, IMO, the goal is to make users happy :) by creating better software (with less resource consumption).

Comment: Sure , so why don't to set all the extensions on `"persistent": false` probably there is any reason ..

Comment: @URL87, some extensions have to be "persistent" because they use `setTimeout` or `SetInterval` or any of async API. You can read about restrictions in the [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#transition)